# What does this do: $this->var1 = function($var2);?

Tags: php, oop

I'm in the process of learning OOP PHP. I already got my head round parent-child class relations and interacting with each other, so all good on that front.

This line of code though confuses me and I'm not exactly sure what it does:

```
$this->var1 = function($var2);
```

Information that may give you a clearer idea of the code: It is a line located inside the constructor of a class and var1 is declared immediately above as private. The function to be called is placed outside the class, but in the same file.

I know that in essence it calls the function of the current class while passing it $var2. But what exactly does the "var1 = " part do? And why is the dollar sign not included?

The syntax works, as I'm looking at somebody else's code and it produces the required results. I'm just trying to learn it for future reference.

Thank you in advance.

Nolo

Comment: Does it say this literally or is `function` some other name of some function? That's kinda important since `function` is a reserved keyword with special meaning.

Comment: take a closer look at the PHP documentation on [properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: Thanks outis. Been doing that. :)

Deceze, no that's not what it says. I just made the syntax generic, because at the time I knew what each part was, but could not translate the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It sets the `var1` field of the object `$this` to the value returned by the function. The dollar sign is needed to resolve what `this` is (an object), and the `->var1` tells php to find that object's `var1` field, so no `$` needed there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `function` is actually the name of a function, and not defining some function, it will set the property `var1` on the current class instance (that's what `$this` is) to the result of `yourFunction($var2)`;

For example:

```
class MyClass {
    public $id;

    function updateId($newid) {
        $this->id=$newid;
    }
}

$test=new MyClass();
$test->updateId(50);

echo $test->id;
```

The output of this script would be `50`.

By calling the `updateId()` function, the class updates its own internal variable, `id`.

Comment: It might also help to clarify that the OP's a little off with this part: "it calls the function *of the current class*".

Answer (score 0):

It stores the result of function ($var2) inside $var1.

In procedural php, the same would be `$var1 = nameOfFuction($var2);`

Inside a class, variables are not accessed directly. Instead, the syntax becomes:

`$this->` indicates that you are accessing a property (a variable) of the current class. var1 is the name of the property.

When the class is created, the constructor method (function inside a class) is called, and var1 is automatically filled with the result from nameOfFuction($var2).

When a property is "private", it means that it can not be called from outside the class, which means it will be used within the class only and possibly accessed through a public method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this
```

refers to the current class instance and

```
$this->var1
```

essentially refers to the variable/property $var1 of this class instance (usually declared or used in combination with magic methods such as __get or __set

check this out for reference to magic methods

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 0):

When you define a class in PHP you are able to give the class instance variables as well as function variables:

```
class Foo
{
  public $bar = 'bar';

  public function __construct($bar)
  {
    echo $bar;  //this line will echo 'baz'
    echo $this->bar; //this line will echo 'bar';
  }
}

$foo = new Foo('baz');
```

To access properties of an instance of a class you need to use the object as a reference. Externally it would be:

```
$foo->bar = 'fizz';
```

Whereas internally it is:

```
$this->bar = 'buzz';
```

So in conclusion, the line in the constructor is setting the value of `$obj->var1` to the result of `function($var2)`.